# Код всегда использует случай else

Tags: php, mysql

Понимаю, что должен сам найти и исправить и копаться в моём никто не должен, но если кто поможет буду благодарен. никаких ошибок не показывает, а просто всегда использует случай else 
вот код формы

```
<form action="/engine/output.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal payment-form">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="payout-rbx">Количество:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cash" required="" id="cash">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="payout-nickname">Ник:</label>
            <input id="wallet" class="form-control" type="text" name="wallet" required="" id="">
        </div>
<input type="submit" value="Вывести" class="btn-pay">
</form>
```

а вот код обработчика, что не так? за ранее спасибо.

```
<?php
require("db_connect.php");
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$db_data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$uid'")->fetch();
$cash = $db_data['balance'];
if(isset($_POST['cash'])) {
  $amount = $_POST['cash'];
  if($amount <= $cash && $amount != 0) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET balance = balance - :amount WHERE uid = :uid");
    $stmt->execute(array(':amount' => $amount, ':uid' => $uid));
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO cashout VALUES(NULL, :uid,:amount,:wallet,:date,:statusv,:balance)");
   $stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $uid, ':amount' =>$amount, ':wallet' =>$_POST['wallet'], ':date' =>time(), ':statusv' =>'0', ':balance' =>'balance'));
     header("Location: /output");
    exit();
  } else {
    header("Location: /output");
    exit();
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Можете вывести( var_dump($_POST); ) перед if'ом?
И я думаю, что если переменная численная, то стоит преобразовать ее к числу ( $amount = (int)$_POST['cash']; )

Comment: Пожалуйста, не вандалируйте сообщения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если код всегда использует случай `else`, это означает, что условие в `if` всегда возвращает `false`.

Отсюда мы можем сделать логический вывод, что либо `$amount` всегда меньше `$cash`, либо `$amount` равен нулю.

Для того чтобы научиться верить своим глазам, можно перед условием вывести участвующие в нем значения,

```
var_dump($amount,$cash); die;
```

после проверки этих значений можно двигаться дальше по коду, проверяя то, как эти значения получаются. [Этот процесс называется отладкой и занимает большую часть времени программиста.](http://phpfaq.ru/debug#debug)

Comment: Но проблема в том, что это не так, как это возможно в теории?

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)